# Google Photos is using all of my quota even though I'm uploading as "High quality"

Tags: google-photos, online-storage

I have a 25 GB limit and have been uploading JPEGs to Google Photos.

I have set it in Google Photos options so they are uploaded as High quality (free unlimited storage), and verified that they are in fact less than 16mp (4096x4096) once uploaded.

However I see now that I am using 88% of my quota (before I started uploading JPEGs I was using about 3%).

Does anyone know if this is a bug or am I doing something wrong?

FWIW, I am using the jfriedl Picasa plugin to upload the JPEGs from Adobe Lightroom 6.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the High Quality setting, the photos should be uploaded by using the new Google Photos apps:

- for mobile devices, Android or iOS
- for computers, Mac OSX or Windows

Other apps like Google Drive or Picasa or plugins, will not have a way to choose and apply the High Quality option in order to save storage quota.

**References**

- [Back up photos & videos from a mobile device](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?hl=en)
- [Back up photos from your computer](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156099?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Try the *Recover Storage* option to compress your pictures.

**Menu** -> **Settings** -> **RECOVER STORAGE**

This will compress items uploaded elsewhere on Google, such as Google+, Blogger, & Picasa Web Albums, however, it does not affect items uploaded through Google Drive.