# Choose which photos in Google Photos to change from Original to High quality

Tags: google-photos, image-storage

I want to save some space in my Google storage.
For Google Photos, I am using Original quality, which counts against my 15Gb quota.

I know I can [Recover storage](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6374270), which changes all photos from Original to High quality ([except for a few cases](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791), including photos uploaded to Google Drive).

**Is it possible to change only selected photos/albums from Original to High quality?**

I guess I could re-upload the photos I want to keep with Original quality to Google Drive, so they would be "immune" to Recover storage, but that is extremely cumbersome.

Related questions:

[Google Photos is using all of my quota even though I'm uploading as "High quality"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80821/google-photos-is-using-all-of-my-quota-even-though-im-uploading-as-high-qualit?rq=1)

[Google Photos vs Google Drive: How do I find out which copy of my photos in my Google Account is the original?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119799/google-photos-vs-google-drive-how-do-i-find-out-which-copy-of-my-photos-in-my-g?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can have only one option selected which will be applied to all photos. However, you can always set up a secondary account and have one for **Original** and the other one for **High quality** and connect both accounts with **Shared libraries**

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a useful workaround. It seems to have some limitations (e.g, can one have albums with pictures from both accounts?) I haven't tried this yet.